# How does all the various Stack Exchange functionality work?

Tags: support, faq

**The FAQ**

If you want to know how asking/answering, tagging, voting, bounties, or whatever works, all the answers are linked from the Meta Stack Exchange master FAQ question: **[FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)**.

For some weird reason there's no link to that FAQ in our FAQ (and we can only edit the first "What kind of question should I ask here" section so we can't add it).  Sorry.

**RPG.SE Works Like The Other SEs**

RPG.SE is a "skinned" version of the same Stack Exchange engine that powers Stack Overflow and the other hundred plus sites in the Stack Exchange network.  How this engine works technically is mostly the same across all sites and, except for some configurations we can try to ask the SE Illuminati to change (and we've pretty much been told no every time we have), your local RPG.SE mods have zero control over how site functionality works, nor does anyone tell us when core site behavior changes.

**Keeping Up With Site Functionality Changes**

The coders do change how site functionality works from time to time and the more formal HTML-type documentation tends to be minimal or out of date; the questions in the Meta.SE FAQ aren't always 100% but at least they generally eventually update when the site does. If you want to stay on top of new developments you can do what we have to do, which is watch the main SE blog and Meta.SE to get the info.

**Note: We Don't Control Any Of This**

*RPG.SE mods, even diamond mods, do not have access to any knowledge or documentation or ability to change site mechanics that you don't have access to*.  You can ask questions about how general SE functionality works on RPG.SE Meta, but the answer may already be on Meta.SE (and someone here may or may not know) so consider looking there too. You can ask for changes to how the site's core mechanics work here on our meta or on Meta.SE - you're welcome to ask here and the devs should see it but you may find a lot more eyes/votes on the topic on Meta.SE.

[Return to FAQ Index](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7064/23970)